# Get a linux process cpu use

Tags: c++, linux, cpu-usage

I am trying to figure out how to get a process (specified by PID) CPU use from my C++ application. The code is trivial and there are lots of answers online on how to do it with examples but one thing that puzzled me was from what sources should the various values be sampled.

For example, most examples seem to refer to parsing `/proc/<pid>/stat` but I've seen a few sources (such as chromium source) that actually iterates `/proc/<pid>/task/<thr_id>` and reads the `stat` file for each thread and sums the relevant fields before calculating the processes CPU load.

So the question, is there any advantage of using one approach over the other?

Comment: Either seems like they should work. I suspect Chromium is collecting other per-thread statistics. If you don't need thread information, use the first method.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked various versions of chromium source and it seems that only older versions used the thread stat files; the latest code [here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:base/process/internal_linux.cc;drc=7aa346a8ba6f861859a392d241ee8246303e94c6;l=73) uses just the `proc/<pid>/stat` file. I guess using the thread stat files just gave more granularity to the data which is not required just for a more general 'how much CPU is process X using".